# Is each label for any person for 288 trials in training session the same as 288 trials in evaluation session for BCIC-IV 2a dataset?

Tags: eeg

I have saved the label files and eeg data for each trial in .npy format. Now will it be the
case that any trial, let's say, 12th trial of person 1 in training session label and 12th trial for person 1 in evaluation be the same? Will not there be correspondence between labels files for each person across sessions?